# Disabling/enabling buttons in Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, button, netbeans

I am new to JAVA and Netbeans. I have 4 buttons in my gui: Display, Initialize, Add and Remove. This is what it is supposed to do: when I start it only Initialize should be enabled and others should be disabled. When I click on initialize, it should be disabled and others should be enabled. I already know that `.setEnabled(false)` does not completely work for it. Here is what I have done:

```
private void displayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
final JButton display=new JButton("Display");
final JButton initialize=new JButton("Initialize");
    display.setEnabled(false);
        display.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            initialize.setEnabled(true);
        display.setEnabled(false);
```

And then in Initialize button

```
private void initializeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
final JButton initialize=new JButton("Initialize");
initialize.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            initialize.setEnabled(false);
        display.setEnabled(true);
        }
        });
```

I have done this for rest of buttons as well but it still does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: “it still does not work” is not so specific that we can really help. You have described the desired behaviour pretty accurately. Please describe the observed (wrong) behaviour with the same precision, and I’m sure someone around here will be able to say something helpful.

Comment: You create 2 instances of initialize button.

Comment: By saying 'it still doesnt work' I mean it does not work the way I want to which I mentioned before. The buttons do not disable after I click Initialize button. +brummfondel can you expand on what you mean and how to do that

Comment: I believe what @brummfondel tried to say is that in both of your code snippets is `new JButton("Initialize");`, so in your code you are creating two such buttons. So a potential problem is the listener is not listening on the same button as the one the user clicks, and/or you are not disabling the same button as the one the user sees. You should make sure you have only one initialize button.